# Archivo activity_main.xml no reconoce elementos ni atributos

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, activity, android-manifest

Tengo un proyecto que contiene un elemento WebView pero el editor AndroidStudio no reconoce el elemento ni algunos atributos que son totalmente validos.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Ya probé removiendo el elemento y poniendo otro pero el editor no reconoce ningún elemento.

Aparte, he notado que el archivo AndroidManifest.xml también no reconoce algunos atributos que también son válidos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ese es el archivo build.gradle que tengo y la versión de AndroidStudio es la 4.1.1
Cabe mencionar que después de una actualización del AndroidStudio, fue apareció el problema.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Suele darse el caso de que las bibliotecas externas no están actualizadas, ¿podrías mostrarnos tu build.gradle? Y también especifica la versión de Android Studio que estés usando.

Comment: En este caso es importante agregar tu build.gradle como comenta @MijaelViricochea , pudiera ser tambièn problema al sincronizar el build.gradle, te sugiero inicialmente limpiar y construir nuevamente tu proyecto.

Comment: @Jorgesys Gracias por el consejo, pero esa aplicación ya la había subido a la tienda de googlePlay ¿crees que si vuelvo a construir el proyecto, pueda subirlo a tienda como una actualización del proyecto?

Comment: @MijaelViricochea  La captura del archivo build.gradle que tengo ya lo adjunte y la versión de AndroidStudio es la 4.1.1
Cabe mencionar que después de una actualización del AndroidStudio, fue apareció el problema.